# How to draw a graph of: $A = \{(x,y) \in R^2 ; x^2 \leq y^2 \leq x+1 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How to draw a graph of: $$A = \{(x,y) \in R^2 ; x^2 \leq y^2 \leq x+1 \}$$

I tried to graph every one of the function ($x²$ and $y²$ and $x+1$) by itself and then see where it's less on y coordinate. But it isn't correct

Comment: For y²≥x² , you have |y|≥|x|. So consider sign of x,y and you will get two regions bounded by two straight lines. Then consider y²≤x+1. This is interior region of a parabola. Take intersection of these two regions and you have your answer!

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nvmfc337wt